# Kotlin gradle plugin - how to use custom output directory?

Tags: gradle, kotlin

In seems that Kotlin Gradle plugin ignores the specified compilation output directory:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        kotlin {
            srcDirs 'source/kotlin'
            outputDir = file('work/program')
        }
    }
}
```

The compiler output goes to 'build/classes/kotlin/main' directory instead of 'work/program'.
But outputDir specified in the same way works as expected in Java Gradle projects.

Is there a way to use **custom compiler output directory** with Kotlin Gradle plugin? (versions: Kotlin 1.2.31, Gradle 4.6)

**Update:**
I submitted bug report about this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23807

Comment: Maybe it's **yet another gradle bug**. I've tried `java.outputDir = file("out")` but the Kotlin compilation output is stored in `main-instrumented`...

Comment: The main issue is the variable `main.kotlin.outputDir` *doesn't exist* at all! ***You declared (defined) it*** (not just changed it)! Still now, with plugin `v1.3.11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is workaround, posted by other user in the Kotlin issue tracker:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "work/program")
}
```

(add this fragment in your 'build.gradle' file)

#### Later update

With Gradle 7.x the Groovy syntax for this is:

```
compileKotlin {
    destinationDirectory = file("work/program")
}

compileTestKotlin {
    destinationDirectory = file("work/proof")
}
```

if you use the Kotlin syntax, it is a bit longer:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.destinationDirectory.set(file("work/program"))
val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.destinationDirectory.set(file("work/proof"))
```

Note, that your IDE may still compile the classes in different directory. To make Intellij Idea to use the same output directories as Gradle, add theese:

```
pulgins {
    idea
}

tasks {
    idea {
        module {
            outputDir = file("work/program")
            testOutputDir = file("work/proof")
        }
    }
}
```