# Change Kotlin .class output directory

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

Currently, Kotlin is compiling .class files into a different output directory than Java:

Java:

```
<module>/build/intermediates/classes/<flavor>/<buildType>
```

Kotlin:

```
<module>/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/<buildVariant>
```

This is causing me a headache with some post compilation tasks. How do you configure Kotlin to generate class files into a different directory?

Answer (score 0):

The following should be what you are looking for. Keep in mind you will have to reference the proper source sets.

gradle.build:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    //if you truly want to override the defaults:
    output.resourcesDir = file('out/bin')
    // Compiled Java classes should use this directory
    java.outputDir = file('out/bin')
  }
}
```

Another nice thing here is also pointing the kotlin/java source directories through the gradle such as:

```
sourceSets {
    main.kotlin.srcDirs += 'src/main/myKotlin'
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/myJava'
}
```

Of course these can be combined in one sourceSet block

Source:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.SourceSetOutput.html

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin plugin doesn't use outputDir in the same way the Java plugin does.

Try this workaround:

```
tasks.withType(org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile).all {
    destinationDir = new File(buildDir, "work/program")
}
```

See this other SO answer: [Kotlin gradle plugin - how to use custom output directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49638136/kotlin-gradle-plugin-how-to-use-custom-output-directory)
And the Kotlin plugin issue filed as a result: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-23807